# How can I call function selected amount of times?

Tags: javascript, loops, dropdown

I'm trying to run function getOrderData number of times that user selected in the dropdown, how can I do that?

Jade file:

```
p
strong Number of pieces:
select(id='numOfPieces')
```

Javascript file:

```
function getOrderData() {
      //this just creates the dropdown dynamically so I could get number that user selected by index value
      const dropdown = document.getElementById("numOfPieces"); 
      var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]; 
      
      for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
          var opt = options[i];
          var el = document.createElement("option");
          el.textContent = opt;
          el.value = opt;
          dropdown.appendChild(el);
      }

    //checks selected number
    let times = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
}

  $("#yes").click(function () {
    
    getOrderData();
}
```

Comment: Simplest way would be use a for loop for how much ever times you want to run the function. Share your html code as well for better explanation

Comment: @SalomiEdward I dont have html for that, I use Jade, its above javascript in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getOrderData() {
  alert('Hallo!!');
}

$("#yes").click(function () {
  let value = $('#numOfPieces').val();
  value = value && value>0 ? parseInt(value) : 1;
  for (let i = 0;  i < value; i++) {
    getOrderData();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `times()` method from [30 seconds of code](https://www.30secondsofcode.org/js/s/times). Here is the code from that website, plus an example:

```js
const times = (n, fn, context = undefined) => {
  let i = 0;
  while (fn.call(context, i) !== false && ++i < n) {}
};

times(5, i => console.log(`Called ${ i } times.`));
```